# Why can't SBT's thread context classloader load JDK classfiles as resources?

Tags: scala, jvm, sbt, classloader

```
lihaoyi test$ tree
.
└── Foo.scala

0 directories, 1 file

lihaoyi test$ cat Foo.scala
object Main{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("java/lang/String.class"))
    println(getClass.getClassLoader.getClass)
    println(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("java/lang/String.class"))
    println(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader.getClass)
  }
}

lihaoyi test$ sbt run
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/lihaoyi/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to test (in build file:/Users/lihaoyi/Dropbox/Workspace/test/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/lihaoyi/Dropbox/Workspace/test/}test...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/lihaoyi/Dropbox/Workspace/test/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Running Main
sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@18e38ff2
class sbt.classpath.ClasspathUtilities$$anon$1
null
class sbt.classpath.ClasspathFilter
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed 29 May, 2017 4:14:11 PM

lihaoyi test$
```

Here, we can see that the `getClass.getClassLoader` and the `Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader` are returning different values. What's more, the `Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader` seems to be refusing to load `java/lang/String.class`, while the other can.

Notably, when I run the jar file using an external tool like `scalac`/`scala`, or `java`, both classloaders are able to load the classfile as a resource

```
lihaoyi test$ scalac Foo.scala

lihaoyi test$ scala Main
sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@1b28cdfa
class scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader
sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@7229724f
class scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader
```

I would expect SBT to behave similarly: to have the `Main.getClass.getClassLoader` and the `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader` both be able to load `java/lang/String.class` as a resource. What gives?

Answer (score 3):

Some hints provided by Jason Zaugg (retronym)'s [sbt launcher notes](https://gist.github.com/retronym/5eba5edabca36fc0b917b5f0095ce990).

> sbt/launcher is a small Scala application that bootstraps an arbitrary Scala program (typically, SBT) described a config file and sourced via Ivy dependency resolution.
>
> This creates a child classloader containing Scala 2.10.6. A child of this contains SBT itself and xsbti/interface-0.13.11.jar.
>
> SBT needs to use non-standard classloader delegation to selectively hide classes when creating child classloaders for plugin code, for the Scala compiler, or for user code.

Some more hints in the sbt 0.13 sources:

- https://github.com/sbt/sbt-zero-thirteen/blob/v0.13.15/run/src/main/scala/sbt/Run.scala#L57-L62
- https://github.com/sbt/sbt-zero-thirteen/blob/v0.13.15/util/classpath/src/main/scala/sbt/classpath/ClasspathUtilities.scala#L71-L72

```scala
def makeLoader(classpath: Seq[File], instance: ScalaInstance, nativeTemp: File): ClassLoader =
  filterByClasspath(classpath, makeLoader(classpath, instance.loader, instance, nativeTemp))


def makeLoader(classpath: Seq[File], parent: ClassLoader, instance: ScalaInstance, nativeTemp: File): ClassLoader =
  toLoader(classpath, parent, createClasspathResources(classpath, instance), nativeTemp)
```

Basically sbt is a kitchen sink of a Java application that has an arbitrary Scala versions and your code, and your test libraries along with the Oracle/OpenJDK's Java library. To construct a classpath that makes sense without loading them over and over again, it's creating a hierarchy of classloaders each filtered by some criteria. (I think)

Answer (score 2):

Notably, one way to work around this issue is to set

```
(fork in run) := true,

(connectInput in run) := true,
(outputStrategy in run) := Some(StdoutOutput),
```

That seems to solve this problem, (`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("java/lang/String.class")` now works) but introduces other unrelated problems (forked JVM takes a moment to boot, boots cold and takes time to warm up...)